# How to implement a search feature using variables from another class (C#)?

Tags: c#, arrays, search

I am making a small project where a user enters information about a movie into an array, and can then search the title to find out the previously entered information.
However, my current search function, at the end of the code, returns:

```
System.String[]'s age rating is System.Int32[]
System.String[]'s genre is System.String[]
System.String[]'s rating is System.Int32[]
```

How do I get the code to load the desired information as opposed to what it is currently returning?
See code below.

```
static void Movie(string[] MovieTitle, string[] Genre, int[] AgeRating, int[] Rating)
                {
                for (int i = 0; i < Rating.Length; i++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("What is the title of the movie?");
                    MovieTitle[i] = (Console.ReadLine());
                    Console.WriteLine("What is the age rating of the movie?");
                    AgeRating[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                    Console.WriteLine("What is the genre of the movie?");
                    Genre[i] = (Console.ReadLine());
                    Console.WriteLine("What is the user rating of the movie?");
                    Rating[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                    
    
                }
            }
            
            static void Main()
            {
                string[] MovieTitle = new string [5];
                int[] AgeRating = new int [5];
                string[] Genre = new string [5];
                int[] Rating = new int [5];
                int position;
                string search;
    
                Movie(MovieTitle, Genre, AgeRating, Rating);
    
                Console.WriteLine("What movie do you want to see?");
                search = Console.ReadLine();
                position = Array.IndexOf(MovieTitle, search);
                Console.WriteLine(MovieTitle + "'s age rating is " + AgeRating);
                Console.WriteLine(MovieTitle + "'s genre is " + Genre);
                Console.WriteLine(MovieTitle + "'s rating is " + Rating);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not accessing a single item, you are using the array itself when printing out the info. You need to use `position` to look up a specific element in the array:

```
Console.WriteLine(MovieTitle[position] + "'s age rating is " + AgeRating[position]);
Console.WriteLine(MovieTitle[position] + "'s genre is " + Genre[position]);
Console.WriteLine(MovieTitle[position] + "'s rating is " + Rating[position]);
```

Also you might want to add a bound check since the `IndexOf` will return -1 if the element is not found in the array.